# SQL iterate through arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Is there a way to iterate through an array in SQL not using stored procedures? For instance given:

```
a | b
--+------
a | {1,2}
```

I would like to flatten the array into individual rows as in:

```
a | b
--+---
a | 1
a | 2
```

Clarification: I am trying to do this in Postgres and am looking for a *pure SQL* solution as opposed to using stored procedures. Please correct me if I am wrong but I don't think this has been addressed in previous questions. Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS?  [One possible way](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/how_to_split_a_string_into_a_set_of_rows_anti_listagg12?lang=en),  [and another](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html)

Comment: @muistooshort, Yes, my mistake. How do you unvote-to-delete?

Comment: @Ben: I don't think you can, maybe check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. Anyway, it takes five votes to close so hopefully people will be responsible and read the comments before agreeing with you :) I'm pretty sure we've all made bad close-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple

```
select a, unnest(b)
from t
```